# Converting XML into JSON to Deserialize into class

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, json.net

Looking for some help here.  I have a situation where we are getting this type of XML from a web service call.

```
<root type="object">
    <dealId>2959</dealId>
    <dealDetailId>2</dealDetailId>
    <localeId>1542</localeId>
</root>
```

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
public class Info
{
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string dealId { get; set; }
    public string dealDetailId { get; set; }
    public string localeId { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestXMLToJson()
{
    string xml = @"<root type=""object"">
                        <dealId>2959</dealId>
                        <dealDetailId>2</dealDetailId>
                        <localeId>1542</localeId>
                    </root>";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
    Info deal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(jsonText);
}
```

When I run through this and look at the jsonText I get the following results:

```
{"root":"@type":"object","dealId":"2959","dealDetailId":"2","localeId":"1542"}}
```

which looks like this in Json Viewer:

```
{
    "root": {
        "@type": "object",
        "dealId": "2959",
        "dealDetailId": "2",
        "localeId": "1542"
    }
}
```

I sure hope I am just doing something stupid and any help you can give would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the XML to JSON without the `root` object wrapper, you need to pass `true` for the `omitRootObject` parameter of the [`SerializeXmlNode`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode_2.htm) method.  Change this line:

```
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

To this:

```
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

That will produce the following JSON from the XML:

```
{"@type":"object","dealId":"2959","dealDetailId":"2","localeId":"1542"}
```

You may also need to use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute on the `@type` property in your model to get it to deserialize cleanly.  I was not able to get it to work without that.  I would recommend doing that anyway so that you can follow normal C# naming conventions not have to deal with the ugly `@` all over your code:

```
public class Info
{
    [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dealId")]
    public string DealId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dealDetailId")]
    public string DealDetailId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("localeId")]
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sJpKl3

---

All that said, why do you need to convert to JSON anyway, if your ultimate goal is to deserialize the XML into a model?  You can use [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to do that directly.

First, mark up your model like this:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Info
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dealId")]
    public string DealId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dealDetailId")]
    public string DealDetailId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("localeId")]
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize like this:

```
string xml = 
@"<root type=""object"">
  <dealId>2959</dealId>
  <dealDetailId>2</dealDetailId>
  <localeId>1542</localeId>
</root>";

StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Info));
Info info = (Info)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LibYVu